Woman finds man with two hearts washed ashore
Can anyone identify a little known film made in late 1970s? 
I guess about a woman who finds a man washed ashore, he turns out to have two hearts, healing powers and in the end is a cloned time traveler, searching for his brother. His brother was probably Christ. She falls in love with him and it ends with him dying, but not too long afterwards the woman finds another man washed ashore, a new clone. 

Anyone else want to call this one Doctor Who?

@Catija Thought number one. :D

No, it's not actually Dr. Who. ;) You're looking for The Next One (AKA The Time Traveller) from 1984:

In this standard sci-fi romance, the widow Andrea lives on a Greek island with her son Timmy and, like the other islanders, is amazed when a stranger, Keir Dullea, washes up on shore during a magnetic storm. She brings the apparently injured man home to help him recuperate his health, and a relationship develops between the two of them. At first seeming to suffer from amnesia, the stranger has a mysterious quality that comes more into focus when he performs certain miracles. As he demonstrates his powers, it is slowly revealed that he is a time-traveler, and his brother, in fact, once traveled back 2,000 years further in time.

He also has 2 heartbeats. Here's the trailer:



